# Export Email Templates and Image Assets from ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, data-export

Is there a way to package and download all of our email templates and images from ExactTarget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not through the app.

The support team may be able to execute some SQL scripts on the database for you though. How willing they'd be to do this and whether it's definitely possible is something you'd need to ask them.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually something that would require a service engagement to pull out of the application, support would not be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I know that I'm late for the party here, it is possible to export the content assets/email from the package manager which is available in Platform for MC administrators.